# SSRS 2017: Want to set a parameter to a default of NULL in a shared dateaset

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, null, type-conversion, default

### the problem

I have a problem with a SSRS 2017 shared dataset.

This dataset is calling a stored procedure. One of the SP's parameters is of type `DateTime`. Within the dataset's parameters dialog I've set the default to `(Null)`. But this seems to be ignored...

With paginated reports everything works fine. The defined report parameters (or *built-in* parameters) can be used to pass valid values.

But when I try to use this dataset within a mobile report I get an error. I cannot even add the dataset! After quite some search I found, that the SP was called with a blank instead of `NULL` (*Pofiler tells me*: `,@ClientTime=N''`), hence the type conversion to `DateTime` failed.

I do not want to change this parameter to a string type, because this report will run in various environments. The correct date getting into the stored proc if taken as string is really awful: `Nov 14 2017  3:35PM` (culture and language dependant!) I do not want to rely on any conversion from string!

### the question

How can I force a SSRS shared dataset to use a real `NULL` for a parameter?

Comment: It might be an obvious question but have you set the 'Allow NULL Value' option on the parameter properties?

Comment: @AlanSchofield, sure...

Comment: Hi @AlanSchofield, I just added an answer myself, might be interesting for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a solution... Not really a solution to the problem, but it seems to help me out:

```
DECLARE @blank VARCHAR(1)='';
SELECT CAST(@blank AS DATETIME) AS toDateTime
      ,CAST(@blank AS DATETIME2) AS toDateTime2
      ,CAST(@blank AS TIME) AS toTime
      ,CAST(@blank AS DATE) AS toDate
      ,CAST(@blank AS BIT) AS toBit
      ,CAST(@blank AS INT) AS toInt
      ,CAST(@blank AS FLOAT) AS toFloat
```

the result

```
toDateTime          toDateTime2         toTime      toDate      toBit toInt toFloat
1900-01-01 00:00:00 1900-01-01 00:00:00 00:00:00    1900-01-01  0     0     0
```

The reason for the error on adding the dataset to a mobile report did not come from the DATETIME-conversion of a blank string but from a deeper place within my T-SQL-code, where I caculated a time difference and did not expect a value of `1900-01-01`. The error message is very large, half of the screen is covered with text, but there's no real hint about the reason...

But this throws an error, hence I'll avoid data types not converting from a blank natively:

```
SELECT CAST(@blank AS decimal(10,4)) AS toDecimal
```

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 10
> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

That means: I have to take the value `1900-01-01` as `NULL`. Still it is rather silly, that SSRS allows parameters with a default of `NULL` but to send a blank in the background.

If there are other solutions which lead to a real `NULL` I'd still be happy to read them!

### UPDATE: Fun fact

The profiler tells me, that a paginated report passes a parameter set to `(Null)` as a blank (as shown in the question). But with a mobile Report the `(Null)` is passed over as `,@DateTimeFrom=N'Nothing'`. The default value must be set to an empty value, which is taken as blank...

Answer (score 1):

Are you hosting this dataset in SharePoint? If so, are you sure the default value is actually set on the SharePoint saved version? I've always observed, that while you can set the value to null in your report designer, when it saves to SharePoint, the null default is lost.  Simply, edit the dataset parameters from the SharePoint interface and select Null for the appropriate parameter after you have saved it. Although I haven't profiled parameters in a long timer, I often do a "@param IS NULL" test within my SQL and have never had issues.

Note that you don't have to do this each time you edit the dataset/report in the future, just on the initial save.

Comment: No, not SharePoint... The T-SQL part is NULL-save... The point is, that I really want to pass the date as a typed value (and not as a string!), but if the SP declares this param as DATETIME, I cannot even add it to the mobile report. The passed in value is a blank string instead of a NULL... So this fails *before* it enters the SP...

Comment: Hi Daniel, I just added an answer myself, might be interesting for you...

Comment: Hi, thx for keeping on! My problem occured **without a report parameter**. I wanted to add my SP to a **mobile** report. I could not add this with a huge error message (a full .Net-CallStack), but no real hint... With a similar test like yours I encountered, that a value of `1900-01-01` was written into the db.